# 'cordova run' with java-11 fails

Tags: cordova

I am using `cordova 12.0.0`, `OpenJDK-11`, `grade-7.5.1`.  `cordova build` works and I can even deploy and run the .apk on a device, but `cordova run`, which I need for debugging, fails with :

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\16515\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\16515\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\16515\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list avd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

It appears to want Java-1.8 but "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run"... can I make this work with Java-11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `avdmanager` was from `Java 8`, I needed change path to use the one located here:

```
> "C:\Users\\[me]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\<cmdline-tools_version>\bin"
```